# Converting variable with 5 digit numbers and dates into date values

Tags: r, dplyr, lubridate, openxlsx

I have the following data, which contains some date values as 5 digit character values. When I try to convert to date, the correct date changes to `NA` value.

```
dt <- data.frame(id=c(1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2),
  Registrationdate=c('2019-01-09','2019-01-09','2019-01-09','2019-01-09','2019-01-09',
'2019-01-09',"44105","44105","44105","44105","44105"))
```

Expected value

```
   id Registrationdate
1   1       2019-01-09
2   1       2019-01-09
3   1       2019-01-09
4   1       2019-01-09
5   1       2019-01-09
6   1       2019-01-09
7   2       2020-10-01
8   2       2020-10-01
9   2       2020-10-01
10  2       2020-10-01
11  2       2020-10-01
```

I tried using

```
library(openxlsx)
dt$Registrationdate <- convertToDate(dt$Registrationdate, origin = "1900-01-01")
```

But I got

```
1   1             <NA>
2   1             <NA>
3   1             <NA>
4   1             <NA>
5   1             <NA>
6   1             <NA>
7   2       2020-10-01
8   2       2020-10-01
9   2       2020-10-01
10  2       2020-10-01
11  2       2020-10-01
```

Comment: You need a conditional test to convert your character to date in one of two ways. Perhaps look for a dash (`-`) and, if found, use `lubridate::ymd()`. Otherwise, do what you are doing now. `ifelse` will be helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one approach using a mix of `dplyr` and base R:

```r
library(dplyr, warn = FALSE)


 dt |> 
  mutate(Registrationdate = if_else(grepl("-", Registrationdate), 
  as.Date(Registrationdate),
  openxlsx::convertToDate(Registrationdate, origin = "1900-01-01")))
#> Warning in openxlsx::convertToDate(Registrationdate, origin = "1900-01-01"): NAs
#> introduced by coercion
#>    id Registrationdate
#> 1   1       2019-01-09
#> 2   1       2019-01-09
#> 3   1       2019-01-09
#> 4   1       2019-01-09
#> 5   1       2019-01-09
#> 6   1       2019-01-09
#> 7   2       2020-10-01
#> 8   2       2020-10-01
#> 9   2       2020-10-01
#> 10  2       2020-10-01
#> 11  2       2020-10-01
```

<sup>Created on 2022-10-15 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Answer (score 2):

```
library(janitor)
dt$Registrationdate <- convert_to_date(dt$Registrationdate)

 id Registrationdate
1   1       2019-01-09
2   1       2019-01-09
3   1       2019-01-09
4   1       2019-01-09
5   1       2019-01-09
6   1       2019-01-09
7   2       2020-10-01
8   2       2020-10-01
9   2       2020-10-01
10  2       2020-10-01
11  2       2020-10-01
```

Comment: That's also my preferred approach, using janitor package.

Comment: I updated your post with a newer janitor function that does essentially what you had but more simply. Hope that's okay :)

Comment: Thank you for the Update but `dt$Registrationdate <- convert_to_date(dt$Registrationdate)` does not work for character date column.  When I convert to date and use this cod then it gives `NA` for the number date.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to import columns in the expected format. An example with `openxlsx2` is shown below. The top half creates a file that causes the behavior you see with `openxlsx`. This is because some of the rows in the `Registrationdate` column are formatted as dates and some as strings, a fairly common error caused by the person who generated the xlsx input.

With `openxlsx2` you can define the type of column you want to import. The option was inspired by `readxl` (iirc).

```r
library(openxlsx2)

## prepare data
date_as_string <- data.frame(
  id = rep(1, 6),
  Registrationdate = rep('2019-01-09', 6)
)
date_as_date <- data.frame(
  id = rep(2, 5),
  Registrationdate = rep(as.Date('2019-01-10'), 5)
)

options(openxlsx2.dateFormat = "yyyy-mm-dd")

wb <- wb_workbook()$
  add_worksheet()$
  add_data(x = date_as_string)$
  add_data(x = date_as_date, colNames = FALSE, startRow = 7)

#wb$open()

## read data as date
dt <- wb_to_df(wb, types = c(id = 1,  Registrationdate = 2))

## check that Registrationdate is actually a Date column
str(dt$Registrationdate)
#>  Date[1:10], format: "2019-01-09" "2019-01-09" "2019-01-09" "2019-01-09" "2019-01-09" ...
```